# How do I list running applications with a DOS batch command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

Background: I use DOS START command to start MyDaemon:

```
@echo off
START "MyDaemon" java -cp test.jar MyTest /B
```

As part of this, I also want to check if MyDaemon is already running. If it is, I don't want to start it again.

The dos command that **doesn't** suit my requirement is:

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq "MyDaemon" > nul
if errorlevel 1 start "MyDaemon" java -cp test.jar MyTest /B
```

and that's because, in the tasklist, the image name is "java.exe", not "MyDaemon". I am looking for the "application name" as seen in task manager, not the image name.

So how can I perform this check to see if MyDaemon is already running using DOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq MyDaemon"
```

Type tasklist /? for further details.

Answer (score 0):

No, you only can enumerate processes. If a process has been launched with parameters (like your'), you cannot see them.

I can give you a solution in .NET to get the application name for processes (or the title of the main window), but I don't think dos can do it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I can write something in Java too, was just wondering if this can be done via dos.